# Error while restoring from Enterprise Edition to Standard Edition

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

I am restoring a database from a SQL Server Enterprise Edition onto a Standard Edition server.  I keep getting an error stating:

> Database 'MyDatabase' cannot be started in this edition of SQL Server because part or all of object 'containedmemebersnapshots' is enabled with data compression or vardecimal storage format. Data compression and vardecimal storage format are only supported on SQL Server Enterprise Edition.

As a result, my database is in suspect mode.

Is there any resolution so I can restore this database onto SQL Server Standard Edition?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately SQL Server Standard Edition does not support vardecimal storage format or data compression.

You need to restore to a Developer Edition (or Enterprise Edition), remove the non-supported features by modifying the objects as necessary, then backup the modified database, prior to restoring it on Standard Edition.

[Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.130).aspx) has a great page detailing what is and what is not supported by each edition.

[MSSQLTips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2108/identify-database-features-restricted-to-a-specific-edition-of-sql-server-2008/) has an article that shows how to use the `sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features` system DMV to identify features that won't be supported on Standard Edition.